# CSS justify Text in Table

Tags: css

it is a question which has been asked already a few times, but none of the answers seem to work for me.

I have a table, in each Datarow I have  with a placeholder for a radiobutton and a text.
All the lines  should be text-align. justify. because it is a story, all the lines should end at the same width.
I tried to use td:first-child like you see it below, and also to use class: line. Somehow the table structure seems to override the justify statement.

Help is as always appreciated

```css
td:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: justify
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px">Header</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_01a% I had heard about her sister ship. It was called the “Titanic” and she had </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_02a% sunken last year. That was it what let me feel fear, although they also promised that this ship </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_03a% the “Olympic”, was even safer than her sunken predecessor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You want the last line to the end of td... Right?

Comment: The content is already getting justified aligned. The last line in case of justify alignment is left as it is. Try adding more content in one of you tds and you will see it.

Comment: Yes, for now all of them should be justified. I know, that I can leave the last aligned-left with  text-align-last. But I will deal with that later.

Comment: @Sunil Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to align all the <td> with each other?

Comment: each time you use justified text on the web, an UI designer dies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `text-align-last: justify;` for the last line and it should work fine.

Have updated the snippet for you:

```css
td:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px">Header</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_01a% I had heard about her sister ship. It was called the “Titanic” and she had </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_02a% sunken last year. That was it what let me feel fear, although they also promised that this ship </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="line">%SM02_03a% the “Olympic”, was even safer than her sunken predecessor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But you need to be careful as not all the browsers support this feature.
Read here: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-align-last for the browser compatibility of this property

Comment: Works very nice, thanks. I have one follow up question. Obviously justify looks awful with just one or two words in each line. Is there a way to select those lines, and text align them left? e.g. .line {text-align: left !important; }

Comment: That will be tricky to do and you will be over complicating the things. Why not you combine the data and show it inside one td tag only. That will be easier to do from a developer's perspective as well as better to read from UI perspective.

Answer (score 0):

IN your code, you are applying the style to each table data  element. So the text is aligned correctly for each .

You can see this is you put it all into one;

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 24px">Header</h1>
<table>
<tr><td class="line">%SM02_01a% I had heard about her sister ship. It was called the “Titanic” and she had 
%SM02_02a% sunken last year. That was it what let me feel fear, although they also promised that this ship
%SM02_03a%  the “Olympic”, was even safer than her sunken predecessor</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you want to keep the rows then try adding the style to a parent tag or add all the text into a paragraph with line spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If what I intend is correct, you want all the lines to end at the same width.

But even if you justify, the lenght of the line will affect your output. In this case, you need put the Justify style to the last line.
Here's a fiddle:

[`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/t9xn4czp/)

Hope this help :)